# Cannot build leksah 0.15.2.0 on linux

Tags: haskell, leksah

When I try to build the latest leksah (using [these instructions](https://github.com/leksah/leksah#building-on-linux)), I get this error:

```
src/IDE/TextEditor/CodeMirror.hs:225:38-56:
    Couldn't match type ‘Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.JavaScriptCore.JSBase.OpaqueJSContext’
                   with ‘webkit-javascriptcore-0.13.1.1:Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.JavaScriptCore.JSBase.OpaqueJSContext’
    NB: ‘Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.JavaScriptCore.JSBase.OpaqueJSContext’
          is defined in ‘Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.JavaScriptCore.JSBase’
              in package ‘webkitgtk3-javascriptcore-0.13.1.0’
        ‘webkit-javascriptcore-0.13.1.1:Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.JavaScriptCore.JSBase.OpaqueJSContext’
          is defined in ‘Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.JavaScriptCore.JSBase’
              in package ‘webkit-javascriptcore-0.13.1.1’
    Expected type: JSContextRef
      Actual type: Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.JavaScriptCore.JSBase.JSGlobalContextRef
    In the ‘cmContext’ field of a record
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘CodeMirrorState {..}’
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
leksah-0.15.2.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: could you show us your `ghc --version`, `cabal --version`, `ghc-pkg list`, did you try to use `stack`?

Comment: seconding the above suggestion. there's a `stack.yaml` which means it should Just Work if you hit `stack build` after installing https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack

Comment: Somehow the package `webkit-javascriptcore` managed to sneak into the build plan, but it doesn't appear to be a dependency (or transitive dependency) of the latest version of leksah. At the very least, you should install in a cabal sandbox - the state of your global package database is simply incompatible with leksah. There is pretty much never any reason to *not* use a sandbox (or stack) anymore - installing anything in the global package db (especially when it's something with 100+ dependencies) is just *asking* for trouble.